# How to properly configure Amplify CI/CD pipeline when using multiple frontends (aws-exports is missing for frontend builds)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-amplify, continuous-delivery

I'm stuck trying to configure a very simple CI/CD pipeline to automatically deploy my frontend application on Amplify. I get an error during the build step.

**To make the long story short :**

- I created a simple project to host my Amplify backend config (it contains only a basic Cognito configuration and a GraphQL Api with only one model : Todos)
- Then I created another project to store a frontend app (a React application)
- I pulled the backend configuration to this frontend project (amplify pull command) and added the whole imports to load Amplify dependencies in my index.js file (including the aws-exports config file). Everything works well locally.

```
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsExports);
```

- I connected my frontend Github repository to Amplify CI/CD though the Web Console to automatically deploy my app each time I push new commits to my `dev` branch. It worked well the first time when I didn't add yet the Amplify configuration in my `index.js` file.
  For sure, I configured my frontend (trough the Web UI) to connect link this one to the target backend environment `dev`

**Git Ignore :**

Please note : the `aws-exports` file is ignored thanks to git ignore.
I would suppose the CI/CD pipeline should automatically add the configuration when assigning the target backend environment to this frontend env.

[Web Form to assign target backend environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrHbX.png)

**Here is the error (build logs) :**

```
2021-03-05T08:20:33.144Z [INFO]: ./src/index.js
                                 Cannot find file './aws-exports' in './src'.
2021-03-05T08:20:33.155Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-03-05T08:20:33.155Z [WARNING]: ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
                                    npm ERR! errno 1
2021-03-05T08:20:33.157Z [WARNING]: npm
```

From my understanding, the Amplify CI/CD service doesn't propagate properly the configuration of the backend before building the frontend app (in my case a Node.js / React stack)

**Any idea to solve this issue ?**

**BTW :** Do you know if we could configure the provisioning step.
I didn't find any information for example to stop the container or to resize the instance.
I don't want to run in on a 24/24 basis and the basic config consume too much resources for my needs.

Kind regards,

Comment: Any solutions for Flutter implementations?

Answer (score 0):

That error is given because in the building step you need to add a configuration for building the backend.
In the **amplify.yml** file in the **building settings** of your app you have to add the following.
[backend-config-build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucd8C.png)

The source is: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-three/